# Applying the same function to each array key in an increasing order in php

Tags: php, function, multidimensional-array

I am using an array in php that updates certain values in the array with the help of a function. The function works perfect but I want to apply the function to each element in an array in a increasing order.

Below is the function name.

```
    CalculateDate($swappedarray,$row,$SetupTime);
```

The argument $row is the key number for each array element.
I want the function to do something like this.

```
    CalculateDate($swappedarray,0,$SetupTime);
    CalculateDate($swappedarray,1,$SetupTime);
    CalculateDate($swappedarray,2,$SetupTime);
```

And so on until the last key number.
While the function works correct. I am just not able to use the for loop for doing this. The code for the 'for loop' which does not work and i tried is as follows.

```
    for ($row = 0; $row <= $maxnum; $row++)
     {                                          
      CalculateDate($swappedarray,$row,$SetupTime);
     }
```

How can I make the function do what I need to do as explained above. Which is apply the function to each array key?

Comment: [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for your problem? (Substitute '$inputarray' for your starting array)

```
function some_callback($rowitem, $key, $userdata)
{
    // echo $key;
    CalculateDate($userdata[0], $key, $userdata[1);
}

array_walk($inputarray, 'some_callback', array($swappedarray, $SetupTime));
```

Basically, array walk is good for calling a function of your choice for each value in the array (similar to array_map, except array_walk makes it easier to pass additional arguments to the callback function).

In this code, we pass your $swappedarray and $SetupTime to the callback by putting them in an array. If $swappedarray does not change as you call CalculateData, it might be better to do the following to avoid recreating the same array:

```
function some_callback($rowitem, $key, $userdata)
{
    // echo $key;
    CalculateDate($userdata[0], $key, $userdata[1);
}

$walk_arguments = array($swappedarray, $SetupTime);
array_walk($inputarray, 'some_callback', array($swappedarray, $walk_arguments));
```

Let me know how it works out for you.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 0):

I just passed the array name in the function argument as a reference and it worked.
        CalculateDate(&$swappedarray,$row,$SetupTime);